# Startup programs on a Mac

Tags: macos

I want to disable certain startup programs. How do I do it on a Mac? The computer loads 4 different programs and I want to eliminate 3 of them.

Comment: What version of Mac OS? What does this question have to do with Safari (which is a browser)?

Comment: Are they loaded at system startup, or only when you login?

Comment: What are the apps? Different apps can use different methods.

Comment: @Tetsujin: You corrected the capitalization issue but overlooked the fact that OP was using the wrong *tag*.

Comment: @Scott - the safari tag may be spurious, but we don't actually know yet until the OP comes back to clarify. Mac vs macOS, I guess sure, hardware vs OS. At least it wasn't tagged mac-address ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to system preferences, users and groups. There is a tab called Login Items. You can click this tab and it shows you which apps are launched at login in. Be sure to 'unlock' the page or you changes won't be stored.

Comment: well, that will cover one of the 4 possibilities; the others being the 'reopen windows when logging back in' option at shutdown/restart, or LaunchAgents & LaunchDaemons, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358410/programmatically-run-at-startup-on-mac-os-x Until we know what the OP is trying to actually do, we can't say for certain.